# Fetching session attributes from static methods

Tags: java, spring

I have used below codes for fetching session attributes from session util class(contains static methods). Want to know that below code could be right approach in multithreaded environment or is there any better other ways for fetching sessions from util.

```
public static HttpSession getSession(){
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
    return session;
}
public static String getEmailIDFromSession(){
    return (String)getSession().getAttribute("USER_EMAIL");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's OK. And it is really thread safe. But from other side you should understand that it will be available only within HTTP Request Thread and from Spring MVC environment.

From other side, if you want to get that attribute from your `@Controller` or `@Service` you always can `inject` session there:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private HttpSession session;

}
```